# Read response body in async request

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, filter

I am wondering how to read response in filter from request body if @Controller method returns Callable interface.

My filter looks like this. Response is always empty. Any solution to this? Is this allowed only using AsyncListener?

```
@Component
public class ResposeBodyXmlValidator extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final XmlUtils xmlUtils;
    private final Resource xsdResource;

    public ResposeBodyXmlValidator(
        XmlUtils xmlUtils,
        @Value("classpath:xsd/some.xsd") Resource xsdResource
    ) {
        this.xmlUtils = xmlUtils;
        this.xsdResource = xsdResource;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper response = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(httpServletResponse);

        doFilter(httpServletRequest, response, filterChain);

        if (MediaType.APPLICATION_XML.getType().equals(response.getContentType())) {
            try {
                xmlUtils.validate(new String(response.getContentAsByteArray(), response.getCharacterEncoding()), xsdResource.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException | SAXException e) {
                String exceptionString = String.format("Chyba při volání %s\nNevalidní výstupní XML: %s",
                    httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr(),
                    e.getMessage());
                response.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE + "; charset=UTF-8");
                response.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
                response.getWriter().print(exceptionString);
            }
        }
        response.copyBodyToResponse(); // I found this needs to be added at the end of the filter
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to handle the async in your filter as well by tapping into the async servlet stuff. However shouldn't the XML validation be done already by the component that writes the XML? Assuming that you are using JAXB and Spring to do the marshaling this is a matter of configuration...

Comment: I agree but this also happens when logging request / responses in other filter and I want to avoid AOP in this case.

Comment: Why would you need AOP for validation? It is a flag you can enable on the JAXB support classes with Spring. Nonentheless if you really want to do things like this in the filter, you will need to tap into the async processing API (detect if a request is async and handle it as such).

Comment: No, forget about validation. Validation example is here only for demonstration purposes. The main problem is that filter which should log request and response bodies does not work either. It logs only request, response is empty. I can replace validation with ResponseBodyAdvice but with this approach, it does convert object to XML 2 times - one for validation and one for serialization to HTTP response

Comment: And for the third time I'm going to tell you that you need to tap into the async processing capabilities of the Servlet API to make this work.

Comment: I know and thank you for your answer but please be objective. Do not argue about how to validate XML and answer to this problem only. I think that title says it clearly: "Read response body in async request"

Comment: I answered that in my very first line in my comment. The other one was a comment on the (imho complex) solution to add validation. Your filter is completely oblivious of the fact it (might) run in an async scenario and only is for the concurrent scenario. You might want to look at the Spring provided `AbstractRequestLoggingFilter` which has async handling (there are some helper methods on the `OncePerRequestFilter` you can use to detect async processing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of Callable is that the dispatcher servlet itself starts async processing and the filter is exited before actually processing of a request.

When Callable arrives to dispatcher servlet, it frees container thread from pool by releasing all filters (filters basically finish their work). When Callable produces results, the dispatcher servlet is called again with the same request and the response is immidiately fulfilled by the data return from Callable. This is handled by request attribute of type `AsyncTaskManager` which holds some information about processing of async request. This can be tested with `Filter` and `HandlerInterceptor`. `Filter` is executed only once but `HandlerInterceptor` is executed twice (original request and the request after Callable completes its job)

When you need to read request and response, one of the solution is to rewrite dispatcherServlet like this:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet(WebApplicationContext context) {
    return new DispatcherServlet(context) {
        @Override
        protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
            ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
            super.service(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);
            responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();
        }
    };
}
```

This way you ensure that you can read request and response multiple times. Other thing is to add HandlerInterceptor like this (you have to pass some data as request attribute):

```
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws
        Exception {
        Object asyncRequestData = request.getAttribute(LOGGER_FILTER_ATTRIBUTE);
        if (asyncRequestData == null) {
            request.setAttribute(LOGGER_FILTER_ATTRIBUTE, new AsyncRequestData(request));
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex
    ) throws Exception {
        Object asyncRequestData = request.getAttribute(LOGGER_FILTER_ATTRIBUTE);
        if (asyncRequestData != null && response instanceof ContentCachingResponseWrapper) {
            log(request, (ContentCachingResponseWrapper) response, (AsyncRequestData) asyncRequestData);
        }
    }
```

**afterCompletion** method is called only once after async request has been completely processed. **preHandle** is called exactly twice so you have to check existance of your attribute. In **afterCompletion**, the response from the call is already present and if you do want to replace it, you should call `response.resetBuffer()`.

This is one possible solution and there could be better ways.

Comment: If I rewrite dispatcherServlet, container thread not released from pool although the code in Callable is executed. Do not know what could be the reason?

Comment: @Rodriguez I think that in case of callable you have to distinguish between DispatcherType REQUEST and ASYNC. I guess that you have to apply request wrapping only for DispatcherType.REQUEST and response wrapping only for DispatcherType.ASYNC